# Can I fetch a database column's spec in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working with a PHP framework whose database model classes are smart enough to upgrade themselves when the schema changes. They do this, in part, by going through a list of checks similar to the following pseudocode:

```
I am version 4.

function UpgradeVersion()
{
    If the DB doesn't yet have a column "foo" in this table,
        I'm version 1. Add the "foo" column.
    If the DB doesn't yet have a column "bar" in this table,
        I'm version 2. Add the "bar" column.
    If the DB still has a deprecated "fargle" in this table,
        I'm version 3. Rename "fargle" to "gargle".
    I'm now up to version 4.
}
```

I've hit a snag in our latest cycle because one of the things we've had to do is expand the size of a column that was created incorrectly in a previous release. So in order to get the model to upgrade itself properly, it can't just decide to upgrade based on a check for the existence of a column; it has to know the current format of the column, and figure out whether it's still too short.

I have looked through the PHP and PDO documents but haven't found a non-experimental, non-deprecated way to fetch this information reliably. The only hack I can think of offhand would be to try an insertion that is longer than the original length, but shorter than the new one, and then selecting the result; if it's truncated, then the column is too short and needs the upgrade. That doesn't seem ideal, though, so I'm casting out here for better alternatives.

Comment: In mysql, you can use information_schema.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` would probably help as well. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the MySQL statment `DESCRIBE myTable;` which will give you information about each column

Comment: Pretty sure `describe` is [SQL 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard.  I'm not familiar with an RDBMS that does not support it.

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is a synonym for `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` in MySQL

Comment: To knit pick I would say that DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN are synonymous.  MySQL reference states: "The DESCRIBE statement provides information similar to SHOW COLUMNS.".

Comment: I ended up using `SHOW COLUMNS` instead of `DESCRIBE` but this proved parseable enough to use. Thanks!